# Sitecore Ordercloud middleware 405 method not found error

Tags: ordercloud

I have successfully set up the `Order cloud` buyer, seller, and middleware on my `Azure VDI` instance, but when adding the product item to the cart the buyer application is giving the below error.

```
PUT request http://localhost:5001/order/X84Gf98P9ke7_vuWBT8qhg/lineitems 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

If I add configuration to remove “WebDAVModule” than 405 error is resolved but now it is giving 404 error

```
 OrderCloud Error: Order X84Gf98P9ke7_vuWBT8qhg not found
 http://localhost:5001/order/X84Gf98P9ke7_vuWBT8qhg/lineitems-- giving 404 Not Found
```

Any idea?
Thanks & regards,
Vikas Chauhan (edited)

Answer (score 1):

The error 404 not found for orderID `X84Gf98P9ke7_vuWBT8qhg` indicates that the order you are attempting to add line items to is not found.  This could be indicative of one of several things.

- Double check that your UserContext is a user that has access to this orderID.
- Ensure that your middleware is configured to utilize an API Client that is part of the marketplace this orderID is part of.
- The last thing to check would be to ensure this order still exists,
  and has not been deleted.